# HTML datetime local - min and max not working properly when using arrows

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

i have created two datetime locals as a range:

```
<form class="dates">
        <label for="minDate">From:</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" id="minDate" value="2018-08-05T10:25:33" required>

        <label for="maxDate">to:</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" id="maxDate" value="2018-10-04T10:25:33" required>
</form>
```

And I then set the min and max values based on my data, such that the range stays within my barchart:

```
document.getElementById("minDate").min = formatDatetimes(xScale2.domain()[0])
document.getElementById("minDate").max = formatDatetimes(d3.timeHour.offset(xScale2.domain()[1],-1))
document.getElementById("maxDate").min = formatDatetimes(d3.timeHour.offset(xScale2.domain()[0],1))
document.getElementById("maxDate").max = formatDatetimes(xScale2.domain()[1])
```

I have then tried to handle events where the inputted values are below/above min/max by setting the value to the min/max value:

```
//function that updates brush when date is changed in one of the input boxes
document.getElementById("minDate").onchange = function() {updateBrush_ondatechange()};
document.getElementById("maxDate").onchange = function() {updateBrush_ondatechange()};

function updateBrush_ondatechange(){

    //make sure that the dates arent outside the barchart area
    if(new Date(document.getElementById("minDate").value)<new Date(document.getElementById("minDate").min)){

         document.getElementById("minDate").value = document.getElementById("minDate").min;

    }

    if(new Date(document.getElementById("maxDate").value)>new Date(document.getElementById("maxDate").max)){


        document.getElementById("maxDate").value = document.getElementById("maxDate").max;

    }

    //move brush to chosen area
    context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, [xScale2(new Date(document.getElementById("minDate").value)), xScale2(new Date(document.getElementById("maxDate").value))]);
```

}

This works perfectly fine when typing a date or selecting a date in the calender (where dates out of range simply can't by chosen or typed). I only experience a problem when using the arrows - if I use the arrows to choose a day or time that is below or above range, my code works perfectly fine, but if I use the arrows to choose a month that is out of range it automatically changes the month to the month of the max date (when I am below the min date, and the opposite happens when I am above the max date).

I don't know if this can be handled somehow, or if maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Which browser are you testing in or do you experience the behaviour across multiple browser? Can you please create a plnkr/stackblitz/jsdfiddle to showcase the problem

Comment: Chrome - and yes, give me a sec :)

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/Skov94/72a22d653b8141cd7036379c500369f2    - the issue, can e.g. be seen if you leave the brush as is, and try to move the month in the second input box one up, by using the arrow :)